# How to conduct performance test on custom Excel add-in and automation functions

Tags: performance, testing, automated-tests, stress-testing, excel-addins

According to MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540.aspx, Visual Studio Professional is not supported in terms of performance and stress testing. I am hoping some one  here can suggest a few free testing tools to me.

Also, I am wondering, what would be the best way to test custom Excel add-in and automation functions? Is there any way that I can automate the testing process for Excel add-in and automation functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What server and interface does your excel add-in use to communicate to the next upstream architectural component?   It is this interface which will dictate what tools can be used to replicate the add-in conversation for performance and stress-testing purposes.   If you are lucky then you may have an interface that is also covered by some open source tools.

Comment: The add-in allows user to interact spreadsheet with forms and then builds up the formula on the fly based on the user inputs. The formula then will use the web service, obtain the data from database and finally populate cells with results. That's pretty much the whole workflow.

Comment: Any performance tool which supports a proxy man-in-the-middle model for recording the HTTP conversation between client and server should be able to trap the call from excel to the server.  You will likely need to set your global proxy settings to the recording proxy for your tool and then set the forward for the recording proxy to your server destination.

Comment: Barring a man-in-the middle approach using a web service to grab your data, you can work with the database administrator to recover your actual query from the database logs and build a direct database virtual user (assuming your performance tool of choice supports a direct to DB virtual user type)